# vue js vuetify v-select, how to access property object from API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've struggle on v-select, I got an array of objects from a back-end api. and i want to render those object to my v-select element.

heres my coe

```
<v-select
      label="Expedition"
      :items="expeditions"
      item-text="expedition"
      :item-value="'deliveryData.expedition'"
      class="custom-select-field"
      variant="underlined"></v-select>
```

But, it's give me output like this
[object Object]

i usually code like this to call data from API

```
<v-textarea
              label="Alamat Lengkap"
              hint="Full Address"
              outlined
              required
              v-model="users.customerData.fullAddress"></v-textarea>
```

i've trie dto add

> item-text
> :item-text

but stil did'nt work.

and also this is piece of my code for script data return

```
data() {
return {
  expeditions: [
    {
      value: "deliveryData.expedition",
    },
  ],
  
};
```

},

Comment: Where exactly does it say `[object Object]`? What do the items in `expeditions` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v-select when given an array of objects as `items`, expects at least two properties on every object:

1. `text`, whose value is the displayed text for that option seen when a user opens the select dropdown
2. `value`, whose value is what gets assigned to the v-model (or otherwise emitted during @change event) when that option is selected.

Therefore, if working with these default options the array of objects you assign to the v-select `items` should be in the form

```js
[
  {
     text: 'Option 1',
     value: 'opt1'
  },
  {
     text: 'Option 2',
     value: 'opt2'
  }
]
```

The user when opening the v-select will see dropdown options "Option 1", and "Option 2".  When either is clicked, the value "opt1" or "opt2" (respectively) is the value assigned/emitted.

What if your objects don't have `text` and/or `value` properties?  What if the objects are from an API and you don't have control of the property names?  This is where the props `item-text` and `item-value` come into play. Their purpose is to change the property names the v-select uses instead of `text` and `value`.

Instead of using the `text` property to lookup what the dropdown label should be, the v-select will use whatever **property name** is assigned `item-text`. Similarly, `item-value` is used to replace the `value` property name.

Given an array of objects like this:

```js
items = [
  {
     expedition: 'Option 1',
     exid: 'opt1'
  },
  {
     expedition: 'Option 2',
     exid: 'opt2'
  }
]
```

The way to assign these as `items` to a v-select is to set the `item-text` and `item-value` like so:

```html
<v-select
  :items="items"
  item-text="expedition"
  item-value="exid"
/>
```

For your specific problem, your objects only have a single `value` property and nothing else.  You should make sure to add `text`, (or some other property used with `item-text` prop) so that the v-select has something to label the option in the UI.